# Maui flyoutitem is not redirecting properly

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm working on a school project lately and I'm pretty new to Maui. I have already implemented CRUD using SQLite database and this works fine so far.

But I have a problem. In my `AppShell`, I have a side-navigation and two of the three links in them work pretty good so far. But everytime I click on the last of the 3 `FlyoutItem`'s, the navigation gets disabled and I can't move anymore. The pages still "switches", but the view stays the same.

This is my Navigation Bar in the `AppShell`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="test_project.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_project"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:test_project.Views"
    FlyoutBackgroundColor="#8319A8"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
    FlyoutWidth="300">

    <FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="house_white.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Albums" Icon="plus_white.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AlbumListPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Songs" Icon="upload_icon.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SongListPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Did anyone ever have a similar problem? I already checked the `DataTemplate` part, this should actually work since its the right name and everything was made properly.

Comment: Debug the constructor of SongListPage

Comment: Could you provide the code for SongListPage so that I can reproduce the situation you described?

Comment: I use a SQLite database, so I'd have to send you about 4 more pages to fully make you understand my code. I guess I just have to search the mistake until I find it, but thanks for the help

Comment: @IlianGionHäsler Well, if it's OK, you can upload [a minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to GitHub.